# PYTHON: Create sublists of same values from nested list into one list

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have a nested list with lists that have two values, a word and a number (sorted by first value - the word):

```
    data=[["apple",2],["cake",5],["cake",8],["chocolate",3],["chocolate",9],["chocolate",10],["grapes",6]]
```

*How can I make it so that it groups items with the same word together as efficiently as possible?*
So to make the list look like so:

```
    data=[ [["apple",2]], [["cake",5],["cake",8]], [["chocolate",3],["chocolate",9],["chocolate",10]],[["grapes",6]] ]
```

The "apple" and the "grapes" are a list of their own, as they only appear once in the original list.

How could this be done? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its what that [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is for :

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> data=[["apple",2],["cake",5],["cake",8],["chocolate",3],["chocolate",9],["chocolate",10],["grapes",6]]
>>> [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(data,key=itemgetter(0)),itemgetter(0))]
[[['apple', 2]], [['cake', 5], ['cake', 8]], [['chocolate', 3], ['chocolate', 9], ['chocolate', 10]], [['grapes', 6]]]
>>>
```

You can use [operator.iemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as the key of your `sorted` function and `groupby`!